# Azure - best way to review logs (web app, redis)?

Tags: azure

I store logs from Azure Web App and Redis Cache in Storage Accounts, but I wonder, what is the best way to analyze them?

Redis seems to store diagnostics information in WADMetrics* tables, while web app puts into storage .csv and .log files, but I dont see any of those as option under the Log Analytics > Workspace data sources > Storage account logs.

Is there a standard (Azure) way to consume, analyze and (preferably) automatically act upon content of those logs?

Comment: I'm not sure, is this what you are looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-how-to-monitor

Comment: did you already check out log analytics ? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/log-analytics/

Comment: Yes, as in my question - I dont see a way for Log Analytics to consume this content. At least neither WADMetrics nor the csv/log files format isnt listed as option when setting up data sources for Log Analytics (unless they are hidden somewhere and I simply dont see them :)) As I look a the "cache-how-to-monitor' article, it may be what I am looking for in Redis context, somehow I was hoping for having everything in one place (web and Redis and databases), but maybe it's too much to ask for :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question, based on the investigation I did so far, maybe it will help someone :)

1. Log Analytics doesn't digest the log data from web apps (I have no idea why, since they seem to be rather standard IIS logs)
2. The only reasonable way I found to consume and analyze log data is with Power BI. You can easily setup Storage account as the data source and then massage the data and get the reports you need.
3. So far I didn't come up with a way to generate alerts based on the content of logs without using tools like Splunk or Sumologic.